# Creating a static copy of a web page on UNIX command line or shell script

Tags: bash, curl, web-crawler, wget, lynx

I need to create a static copy of a web page (all media resources, like CSS, images and JS included) in a shell script. This copy should be openable offline in any browser.

Some browsers have a similar functionality (Save As... Web Page, complete) which create a folder from a page and rewrite external resources as relative static resources in this folder.

What's a way to accomplish and automatize this on Linux command line to a given URL?

Comment: Have you tried the answers from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400935/how-do-i-completely-mirror-a-web-page ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `wget` like this:

```
wget --recursive --convert-links --domains=example.org http://www.example.org
```

this command will recursively download any page reachable by hyperlinks from the page at www.example.org not following links outside the example.org domain.

Check `wget` manual page for more options for controlling recursion.

Answer (score 4):

You want the tool `wget` to mirror a site do:

```
$ wget -mk http://www.example.com/
```

Options:

> -m    --mirror
>
> Turn on options suitable for mirroring.  This option turns on recursion and time-stamping, sets infinite recursion depth and keeps
>   FTP
>          directory listings.  It is currently equivalent to -r -N -l inf --no-remove-listing.
>
> -k    --convert-links
>
> After the download is complete, convert the links in the document to make them suitable for local viewing.  This affects not
>   only the
>          visible hyperlinks, but any part of the document that links to external content, such as embedded images, links to style sheets,
>          hyperlinks to non-HTML content, etc.

Comment: I suggest using --adjust-extension flag for static copies. Without the flag, a URL that ends with a query such as `index.html?id=2` will come out with a file named `index.html?id=2` and won't be recognized as a file to open in a browser. With the flag, the resulting file is named `index.html?id=2.html`.

Comment: '-k' / '--convert-links' is unreliable. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. It is less likely to work during attempts to mirror larger websites.