# static reports for jenkins ci server

Tags: jenkins, report

I am running a Jenkins server that has about 15 jobs. The jobs are triggered by github changes. Each job pulls the changes, builds and runs all the unit tests.

I would like to upload the build and test results to a public site with an Apache webserver. It would be great if the static HTML report pages are linked and also have a nice layout. Is there some plugins / or configuration I can use to get this?

I do not want to have a public facing Jenkins due to security concerns.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really interesting idea. I don't have a complete answer unfortunately, but you may be able to hack something together by creating a job that runs periodically and:

- Use `wget` to create a static copy of your Jenkins site (examples of how to do this are found in [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15849822/1980029)).
- Use the [FTP-Publisher plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/FTP-Publisher+Plugin) (or just a good old `scp`) to copy the output to wherever you want to host the results.

Hope this helps, and would love to know if you're able to get it to work!

Answer (score -1):

[SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/) and the Jenkins Sonar plugin is great for this. You can integrate sonar with jenkins really well. Some of my jobs run various findbugs, pmd directly and fail the build in Jenkins and also run a Sonar report which will do it again.

Comment: I did NOT ask about metrics and static code analysis and such. So this was probably meant to answer a different question?